# Content has been consumed error while parsing HttpResponse

Tags: android, json, apache, web-services, http

I am trying to connect a service then trying to parse json data from it. But when I try to put response into BufferedReader it gives me "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content has been consumed" exception.
As I read it it suppose to happen when I try to get content from response twice but I do it once and it happens anyways and i couldn't understand why this happens.

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
String getURL = AndroidHelper.apiHost + "/enduser";
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(getURL);
get.setHeader("APIKey", AndroidHelper.apiKey);
get.setHeader("SIG", getSIG());
get.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
try {
    HttpResponse responseGet = client.execute(get);

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            responseGet.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));

    try {

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (String line = null; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
            builder.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(builder.toString());
        JSONArray finalResult = new JSONArray(tokener);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        try {
            String json = reader.readLine();
            JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(json);
            JSONArray finalResult = new JSONArray(tokener);
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }

        Log.d("", "");

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.d("ServiceError", "1---" + e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("ServiceError", "2---" + e.toString());
    }
```

Comment: review 'execute' and 'postprocess' ...  http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/protocol/HttpRequestExecutor.html#execute(org.apache.http.HttpRequest, org.apache.http.HttpClientConnection, org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext)

Comment: Thank you man. Now i got the problem.